# VsCode not Auto-importing Django depenencies

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django and working with VsCode. In PyCharm, the imports are working fine.

[PyCharm importing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlfFW.png)

However in VsCode:

[VsCode importing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssAsc.png)

Is VsCode just not capable of this? Or is there something iffy with my configuration?

I have the correct Python interpreter configured as well. I have Pylance installed and it suggests imports automatically for some other things, rather unhelpfully usually.

e.g.,
[VsCode importing unhelpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCGFG.png)

I have tried settings some options in `settings.json`. The `python.analysis.extraPaths` adding the path to django on the Python installation. I have tried `python.analysis.indexing` set to true as well. I haven't found any other solutions.

Comment: Here is the [vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters) for selecting python interpreter, seems like vscode isn't able to detect the right interpreter path.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

#### To solve random error you have to import so write like this on top of your code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

#### And if error is still coming then close vs code and open once again and check django is install or not